# Чи доречно замінити «ало» на «агов»

Tags: вибір-слова

Як на мене слова *ало* і *агов* мають ту саму чи майже ту саму семантику. Наприклад, ми можемо почути, як хтось когось озиває вигукуючи *ало* або *ало, гараж*. Але *агов* служить для цієї ж цілі. Мені здається природнім вживати це слово і під час телефонної розмови. Як ви гадаєте, наскільки це природно? Тобто чи почуватиметься мовник зручно використовуючи це слово в телефонній розмові, чи не йтиме це врозріз із його уявленнями про значення цього слова.

Comment: Уточніть, будь ласка, критерії природності. Чи справді ці слова семантично взаємозамінні?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мою думку, ці слова не зовсім тотожні.

*Агов* зазвичай уживається:

1. Щоб покликати когось чи привернути чиюсь увагу (при цьому, по-моєму, у сучасному світі такий спосіб — коли звертаються не за ім'ям, а якимось вигуком — може звучати доволі фамільярно). Тобто Ви на вулиці можете підійти до когось і сказати: «Агов, іди-но сюди» (але дехто може образитися на таке звертання).
2. Щоб перевірити/утримати зв'язок, який начебто обривається (тобто коли у Вас є серйозні причини думати, що Вас перестають чути). Тобто Ви можете волати у слухавку «Агов! Агов! Чи мене чутно?!» коли є причини думати, що пропадає зв'язок.

*Алло* теж може більш-менш використовуватися в тих самих двох значеннях.

Але чого, на мою думку, бракує слову *агов*, але має слово *алло*, — це такого значення:

3. Нейтральне зазначення «слухаю», «я на зв'язку».

Тобто цілком природньо використовувати *агов* буде, коли зв'язок обривається. Але коли Ви будете вітати співрозмовників (чи принаймні починати сеанс зв'язку) цим словом — це вже може виглядати незвично. (Хоча я не виключаю, що й цього значення слово з часом може набути.)

P.S.: Щодо початку розмови доречним здається [коментар](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/2448202621972436?comment_id=2448426308616734) одного з користувачів у «Фейсбуці»: «Та просто вимовляти „слухаю“ — і жодних проблем».

Comment: Або *на дроті*, та *ало* все ж коротше.

Answer (score 2):

**Алло**
(промовляється як **ало**) уживається при звертанні до особи під час **ділової телефонної розмови** в значенні "слухаю", "слу­хайте" і є невід'ємною складовою правил мовленнєвого етикету.

**Агов**
вживається, коли треба привернути чи­юсь увагу, покликати когось або відгукнутися на чийсь заклик.

Тобто, якщо телефонна розмова допускає вживання фамільяризмів, наприклад, з друзями, то можна використати "агов", але якщо це дзвінок до офісу від клієнта, для перевірки контакту треба казати "ало".